# Asking for a sample project from OP

Tags: discussion

Is it fine if I ask for a sample project, if the OP is struggling with some project-related problems, especially if he's just practicing on a non-production project?

For example: I answer iOS questions, and there's this OP having a problem in auto-layout or having a difficulty in Interface Builder related stuff.

Comment: We prefer to have questions and answers that are self contained. That said; it is not forbidden to ask, as long as you attempt to clarify the question once you looked at the project files so any visitors don't have to do that as well to find the question useful.

Comment: I see. Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: It has been discussed before but I'm a bit short on time atm to either find those supporting posts or judge if a duplicate is applicable. The comment should do for now.

Comment: [Similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195952/is-source-codes-are-free-upon-request-acceptable) from the main meta site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion would be: Not normally.

> provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem

Is the ultimate goal, and usually we can get a very good idea of the problem without a project.

For C# I often find myself asking for a class to be included in the question. As helpful as a full github repo might be, recreating a minimal MVC project that mimics the problem can be arduous.

It's also much better to have everything contained on stackoverflow; dead links are a real problem. External links die, questions and fiddlers get deleted, and repos disappear. I wonder what effects CodePlex for example has on questions and answers here.

I do think there are exceptions however:

Angular, I like to see a question with all the relevant code in the Question. I rarely ask, but sometimes I do. And I usually [answer in this format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057167/understanding-ngfor-from-angular-2/52058014#52058014) where I post the technical information, the code, and a working StackBlitz demo. If something ever happens to the StackBlitz, at least everything that might have been helpful (assuming anyone is still using Angular 5 - 7 when 20 is released) will always be there.

I don't have experience with iOS layout. I would assume it's similar to XAML for WPF / Windows phone and having a little code goes a long way. If the issues are extremely odd, I couldn't reproduce it and the code seems complete, and no answers have come through in a reasonable amount of time I wouldn't hesitate to ask for an external repo with the problem present. Once the issue is found, I'd ensure the original question and/or answer details exactly what was wrong.

Comment: agreed on the issue with external code; however for something like angular or react, version numbering is even more important since the apis can change a lot between versions. I think Stackblitz or whole project snippets elsewhere can help with that, though I guess the real solution is just to include the version numbers or a snippet of the package.json